# Отображение имени в discord Embed

Tags: python, discord.py

[image: введите сюда описание изображения]Столкнулся с такой проблемой делал команду .baka для бота она должна говорить что {упоминание участника} ты Baka, но она вместо упоминания пишет id пользователь. Помогите исправить ошибку.

```
@bot.command()
async def baka(ctx,member:discord.Member):
    r = requests.get(f"https://tenor.com/search/baka-anime-gifs")
    soup = BeautifulSoup(r.content, 'html.parser')
    div = soup.findAll("div", class_="Sticker")
    gif = []
    for link in div[0:15]:
        links = link.find("img").get('src')
        gif.append(links)
    embed = discord.Embed(color=0xff9900, title=f"{ctx.author.name} ты Baka")
    embed.set_image(url=random.choice(gif))
    await ctx.send(embed=embed)
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Надеюсь, я правильно понял суть вопроса

```
embed=discord.Embed(title=“”, description=f"{member.mention}, ты Baka!", color=0xff9900)
```

Comment: Вы правильно поняли суть, да только я тоже так делал и вместо упоминания у меня писался id пользователя.

Comment: ctx.member.mention измените на member.mention, я ошибся в коде.

Comment: Да, я и это писал, все равно id пишет.

Comment: discord.utils.get использовали? Если нет, то код выше, я не успел отредактировать

Comment: Нет, не использовал.

Comment: Попробуйте, должно работать

Comment: Работать не будет, т.к. в `embed` `title` нельзя вставлять упоминания

Comment: Тогда следует поместить текст в description

Comment: Точно! Это же логично и как я раньше не догадался.

Comment: Сарказм не уместен :D

Comment: Это не сарказм :D